# Org mode: Chaning "DONE" to "TODO" automatically for repeating tasks

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to schedule a task that is marked as TODO and something that repeats every day. I have scheduled this task with +1d.

When I am done with this task for today, I change it to DONE and then put down some notes with it.

But now this tasks appears as DONE in the agenda for the next day also.

Is there a way to make org-mode automatically change DONE to TODO for the next day?

Comment: It should automatically update.  Are you using `org-todo` to change the state of the todo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon completion (via C-c C-t d), the task must return to TODO or some other state you define:

```
;; TODO state to which a repeater should return the repeating task.
(setq org-todo-repeat-to-state "TODO")
```

Depending on your configuration (see `org-treat-S-cursor-todo-selection-as-state-change`), it's possible it won't work if you change TODO keywords with the S-arrows.

Comment: You can also set this per-task by setting the `REPEAT_TO_STATE` property.

Comment: At least for me this changes the task immediately to "TODO". It would be great if somehow the task would appear "DONE" for the rest of the day, and then tomorrow when I update the file, it changes back to "TODO". Is that possible?

Comment: See the footnotes in [section 8.3.2 of the org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html#FOOT70) for details about `org-todo-repeat-to-state`.